# Why does ubuntu 13.10 on a AMD fusion boot into a corrupted graphical screen?

Tags: boot, drivers, ati, graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 via the USB installer on my HTPC with Asus F1A75-M with AMD A4-3400. It doesn´t startup to the graphical mode. I do see the Ubuntu boot logo (with red dots) then it switches to graphical mode and stalls on the screen as shown in the figure.  It does boot with the option nomodeset, but then it does not detect the screen at the maximal resolution. Has anyone a clue where this goes wrong and how to solve it?

My goal is to install ubuntu running on the oss drivers ( for xbmc with radeon oss with VDPAU), so I do not like to install the ATI closed source drivers.

Photo of tv screen with corrupted image
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need `fglrx`

press f4 during the purple bootscreen
and then f8 to add '--radeon.modeset=0' to the bootline.

or hold the left shift key during boot to enter the grub menu. with the 'e'key you can add the parameter so that it will boot.

once you have booted, you can install fglrx by entering

```
apt-get install fglrx
```

in a terminal

Comment: Thank your for the answer. However, my goal is to use the OSS radeon driver in order to try xbmc in combination with the open source radeon driver, for which support is under development at the moment (see :http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=17485). Any clue how to get the oss-driver working?